# How to import data from parquet file to existing Hadoop table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have created some tables in my Hadoop cluster, and I have some parquet tables with data to put it in. How do I perform this? I want to stress, that I already have empty tables, created with some DDL commands, and they are also stored as parquet, so I don't have to create tables, only to import data.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of a hive feature that enables you to use parquet to import data.  Even if you don't want to create a new table.  I think it's implied that the parquet table schema is the same as the existing empty table.  If this isn't the case then below won't work as is.  You will have to select the columns that you need.  There

Here the table that you already have this is empty is called `emptyTable` located in `myDatabase`.  The new data you want to add is located `/path/to/parquet/hdfs_path_of_parquet_file`

```
CREATE TABLE myDatabase.my_temp_table
  LIKE PARQUET '/path/to/parquet/hdfs_path_of_parquet_file'
  STORED AS PARQUET
  LOCATION '/path/to/parquet/';
INSERT INTO myDatabase.emptyTable as 
  SELECT * from myDatabase.my_temp_table;
DELETE TABLE myDatabase.my_temp_table;
```

You said you didn't want to create tables but I think the above kinda cheats around your ask.

The other option again assuming the schema for parquet is already the same as the table definition that is empty that you already have:

```
ALTER TABLE myDatabase.emptyTable SET LOCATION '/path/to/parquet/';
```

This technically isn't creating a new table but does require altering you table you already created so I'm not sure if that's acceptable.

You said this is a hive things so I've given you hive answer but really if `emptyTable` table definition understands parquet in the exact format that you have the `/path/to/parquet/hdfs_path_of_parquet_file` in you could just drop this file into the folder defined by the table definition:

```
show create table myDatabase.emptyTable;
```

This would automatically add the data to the existing table.  Provided the table definition matched.  Hive is Schema on read so you don't actually need to "import" only enable hive to "interpret".

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test this out tomorrow at work. hope nobody completed this task already :)